# Connecting to sharded mongo cluster from spring application

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

I'm testing my spring application with a sharded mongo database.

*My config is:*

```
System-1 (Config server and Mongos)

System-2 (Shard0000) [Standalone mongod instance, not a replica set]

System-3 (Shard0001) [Standalone mongod instance, not a replica set]
```

In my tests I'm trying to take down one of the shards and check for consistency of data. My question is how do I configure the spring application.

I've tried,

```
new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoURI("mongodb://System-2,System-3/db-name"));
```

But I get the error

```
Expecting a single StandAlone, but found more than one.  Removing
System-2:27017 from client view of cluster
```

and

```
Expecting a single StandAlone, but found more than one.  Removing
System-3:27017 from client view of cluster.
```

How do I get the config right?

Comment: Just connect to the `mongos` instance. You seem to be following the syntax for connecting to a ReplicaSet, which you don't have. Even if using replica sets, your application only needs to care about the mongos router.